# unable Read windows registry values of restricted or limited access machine or firewall security

Tags: java

To read registry i have running code. but it wont work on restricted environment.
following is the code.

```
private ArrayList<String> getVirtualPrinterlist(){
ArrayList<String> VirtualPrinterlist = new ArrayList<String>();
try{
    String [] keys = Advapi32Util.registryGetKeys (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Print\\Printers" );
    for (String key : keys) {
        System.out.print(key+" #  ");
        String ipString=Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Print\\Printers\\"+key, "Port");
        System.out.println(ipString) );

        VirtualPrinterlist.add(key);

    }
}catch (Exception e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return VirtualPrinterlist;
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you can do anything about it when the environment is restricted. Have you tried if you can see the registry entries without admin rights?

Comment: Most likely your library is buggy - heres a JRE solution without libraries : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6163701/351861

Answer (score 1):

You can not read the Registry from remote systems if the windows firewall is on. This even would not work with windows board tools. If you are in a Domain-Environment, you can define a local or global group policy to set the firewall inactive or off.

Also, windows users (accounts that are only in the group `Users`) do not have the right to write to HKLM, only to their environmental trees like HKCU.

If you want to change registry settings, I recommend you to use the command line prompts by calling over the `Runtime` class. You can also add separate adminsitrator parameters here.